# XPath or BeautifulSoup (or some other way) to select and parse a certain div block

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, beautifulsoup

If there is a page  with similar div blocks, but some of these blocks have an additional block div and I need to pick up data only from divs with the additional block. How can i filter out only the div blocks i need?

For example, i need data from `[div class = 'level_33']`  but only if `[div class = 'level_1']` contains `[div class = 'level_special']`.  Another words, how can  i set such a condition: "Take data from `[div class = 'level_33']`  if it belongs to `[div class = 'level_1']` that contains `[div class = 'level_special']`?

```html
    <div class = 'level_1'>
      <div class = 'level_2'>
           <div class = 'level_31'></div>
           <div class = 'level_32'></div>
           <div class = 'level_33'></div>
           <div class = 'level_special'></div>
       </div>
    </div>   

    <div class = 'level_1'>
      <div class = 'level_2'>
           <div class = 'level_31'></div>
           <div class = 'level_32'></div>
           <div class = 'level_33'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try The following XPath.

```
//div[@class='level_1'][.//div[@class='level_special']]//div[@class='level_33']
```

OR

```
//div[@class='level_1'][.//div[@class='level_special']  and .//div[@class='level_33'] ]//div[@class='level_33']
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath is a good solution. Here is another solution. Maybe it can also solve your problem.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html='''<div class = 'level_1'>
      <div class = 'level_2'>
           <div class = 'level_31'></div>
           <div class = 'level_32'></div>
           <div class = 'level_33'></div>
           <div class = 'level_special'></div>
       </div>
    </div>   

    <div class = 'level_1'>
      <div class = 'level_2'>
           <div class = 'level_31'></div>
           <div class = 'level_32'></div>
           <div class = 'level_33'></div>
      </div>
    </div>   
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
div = doc.getElementByClass('level_special',start='level_1')
if div:
  div = div.parent.getElementByClass('level_33')
  print (div) # {'class': 'level_33', 'tag': 'div', 'html': ''}
```